# Solid torus with nontransparent edge - THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to draw few toruses and balls (spheres) going through them. Problem is: edge of torus should be solid and stop balls, but they are alowing balls to go through them

I tried to use BoxMesh, but its not allowing balls to go throught hoops. i want to made torus: so ball is going throught inside of it, but edge of torus is solid and ball is not going through the edge

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <style>

    #display { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px;
            width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1 }

    .manipulate { text-align: center }

    .view { width: 5in; height: 5in; margin: auto }

    button { width: .75in }

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="viewport"></div>
  <canvas id="display"> </div>
  <script src="three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="physi.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r73/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <script>
    plane = new Physijs.BoxMesh(
      new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 2, 10, 10),
      Physijs.createMaterial(
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
          color: 0xeeeeee
        }),
        .4,
        .99
      ),
      0
    );

for (var i=0;i<50;i++) {
    torus = new Physijs.Mesh(
      new THREE.TorusGeometry(18, 0.2, 16,100),
      Physijs.createMaterial(
        new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
          color: 0x00FFFF,
          transparent:false
        })
      ),
      0
    );
    torus.translateY(i)
    torus.collisions=0;
    torus.rotation.y=Math.PI/24
    torus.rotation.x=-Math.PI/2
    scene.add(torus);
}
    setInterval(function() {
      ball = new Physijs.SphereMesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(
          Math.random() * (4 - 1) + 1,
          16,
          16
        ),
        Physijs.createMaterial(
          new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0xff0000,
            reflectivity: .8
          }),
          .4,
          .99
        ),
        1
      );

      var r = {
        x: Math.random() * (Math.PI - Math.PI / 12) + Math.PI / 12,
        y: Math.random() * (Math.PI - Math.PI / 12) + Math.PI / 12,
        z: Math.random() * (Math.PI - Math.PI / 12) + Math.PI / 12
      };

      ball.rotation.set(r.x, r.y, r.z);
      ball.position.y = 40;
      ball.castShadow = true;
      ball.receiveShadow = true;

      scene.add(ball);
    }, 600);
    window.onload=init
    function init() {


        render();
    }
    scene.simulate()

    function render() {
      for (var i = 5; i < scene.children.length - 5; i++) {
        var obj = scene.children[i];

        //if (obj.position.y <= -50) {
        //  scene.remove(obj);
        //}
      }





  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Plane is solid : Its made of BoxMesh and is preventing all balls to falling through. I want to do same with torrus. I want balls to go through it, but bounce of the edges of torus

Comment: have you tried using ConvexMesh instead of Mesh?

Comment: Yes. Physijs.ConvexMesh gives interesting result but its still not perfect. At first balls appears to be lagging, theythey are trapped in higher toruses, but after some "struggle" many balls still are going through edges of toruses. I also tried to change iteration to +=10 so its only 4 toruses: Now most of balls are bouncing of first, highest torus, some go through first but they are trapped between first and second torus counting from the highest one. I mean torus acts similiar to BoxMesh, its blocking in all of its area, instead of just edge

Comment: what about ConcaveMesh?

Comment: No, i tried all meshes,either they work like BoxMesh (ball is not going throught the torus, like its closed circle plane) or like Mesh, means box is going through torus, but also not bouncing of edge of torus. I want to treat torus like its basketball hoop basically

Comment: i dont think physijs supports this type of geometry

Comment: you can try cannon js https://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/demos/trimesh.html